# What is the difference between ArrayList and ArrayLists?? Both give me different method options

Tags: java, collections

I dont know what the difference between these 2 is? ArrayList and ArrayLists. The ArrayLists only gives me few options of methods to select from like addToSlot but the ArrayList gives me a lot
more options. Why is Java Allowing me to use ArrayLists like ArrayList?

```
class TestList {
        ArrayLists myLists = new ArrayLists();
        ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();
    
        public void add() {
            myLists.addToList("anyValue");
            // the .add method for example only shows for ArrayList not ArrayLists
            myList.add("anyvalue");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you created a class called ArrayLists?

Comment: Post all the `import` statements at the top of that code.

Answer (score 1):

We don't have `ArrayLists` (plural) class in Java. Either you are creating custom class or calling an [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) that has `ArrayLists`. Java has only the [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html) (singular) class.

I am sure you must be creating either your own custom class or using any api that has an `ArrayLists` class .